# Observable.subscribe() works only once (ngrx\angular2)

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, ngrx

I'm subscribing to a store property in a component constructor

```
constructor(private someService: SomeService){
        someService.someObservable.subscribe((data: Some)=> {
            this.some = data;
            console.log('changed');
        });
}
```

In the service, the constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(private store: Store<any>){
        this.someObservable = <Observable<{}>>store.select('some');
}
```

I keep changing the state of this object, but the logging only appear once.
What's also weird is that I'm accessing the `this.some` property directly in my template (without `async` pipe), and it updates perfectly!
It seems like the `this.some` property is being updated, but the `next()` in the subscription isn't working.

help anyone? thanks!

Comment: what does your service look like?

Comment: In the server constructor I'm exposing the `Observable`, like this: `this.some = <Observable<{}>>store.select('some')`

Comment: I'm confused. Is `some` and Observable or your data? can you add more complete code to your example? Preferably something that can be run and reproduce the problem?

Comment: I edited the code. hope it is more clear.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer shouldn't the observable calls `next()` every time there is a change in the store?

Comment: You are right. Sorry, seems I misread your question.

Comment: @JoJoB. do we have a solution for this ? I am also facing this issue

Comment: @sij Not yet, for now I'm using alternatives

Comment: @JoJoB.My issue got fixed with this https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/127 Object.assign({}, state, { logging: true, error: null }); I was not adding an empty object in start. Give it a try

Comment: @sij thanks, I think I did it back then (creating a new object, even in the nested objects), but it didn't work. for now I'm using angular-redux/store and it works fine

Comment: `this.some` is not an observable, it's just a plain old value, so of course you don't need to pipe it into `async`. If you want to use the observable directly in your template, just say `{{someService.someObservable | async}}`. The reason you're only getting one emission is most likely due to the fact that `store.select` is only emitting once.

Answer (score 5):

In my very similar case the problem was that one of the subscription handlers was throwing an error. When an error is encountered the observable stream stops emitting new values.

Comment: This did it for me. It's worth noting that the console had no errors in it whatsoever so for a NGRX novice such as myself this was a tricky one to find.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call for services in the constructor and its considered as a bad practice. Use ngOnInit() method to subscribe for a service. This method will be called automatically when the component is loading.

Try like this, this might solve your problem.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

export class YourComponent implements OnInit{

    ngOnInit():void {
       //handle your subscription here
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Maybe it has something to do with `ChangeDetectionStrategy`?

Comment: your advice is in place but this does not answer the question. placing calculations in your constructor only delays the object's instantiation and you can't access properties

Comment: @svarog, as a matter of fact it won't cause any delay because observable is async. Correct way to implement it is as suggested by `icsapper`.

Comment: @JoJoB. where is your code to publish next events? Are you using EventEmitter?

Comment: @Pradeep I no longer use this code. In my new code I'm accessing `Store` where ever I need it, instead of passing an `Observable` through a service

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are returning a new object from your reducer if you update a property and return same object it would not trigger store update event

switch (action.type) {

```
    case MAIN_MENU_TOGGLE : {
```

Ex return Object.assign({},appSettings, {isMainMenuExpand: flag})
}

Comment: I'm doing it, this is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I find the reason is that you edited state, not created new object for state, for ex:

**Do:  Object.assign({}, state, {smt: changed}) }**

Instead of: Object.assign(state, {smt: changed}) }